# How can I shorten the following C# if statements?

Tags: c#

I would like to shorten the following code however I am not sure where to start.

Are switches the way to go with this?

```
        static string RevisedConversionFunction(string input, string from, string to)
    {
        double exchangeRateUSD;
        double exchangeRateAUD;
        double exchangeRateCAD;
        double exchangeRateEUR;
        double exchangeRateGBP;
        double exchangeRateNZD;
        double fromExchangeRate;
        double toExchangeRate;
        exchangeRateUSD = 1;
        exchangeRateAUD = 1.31;
        exchangeRateCAD = 1.28;
        exchangeRateEUR = 0.95;
        exchangeRateGBP = 0.68;
        exchangeRateNZD = 1.36;
        fromExchangeRate = 0;
        toExchangeRate = 0;

        if (from.Equals("USD"))
        {
            fromExchangeRate = exchangeRateUSD;
        }
        if (from.Equals("AUD"))
        {
            fromExchangeRate = exchangeRateAUD;
        }
        if (from.Equals("CAD"))
        {
            fromExchangeRate = exchangeRateCAD;
        }
        if (from.Equals("EUR"))
        {
            fromExchangeRate = exchangeRateEUR;
        }
        if (from.Equals("GBP"))
        {
            fromExchangeRate = exchangeRateGBP;
        }
        if (from.Equals("NZD"))
        {
            fromExchangeRate = exchangeRateNZD;
        }

        if (to.Equals("USD"))
        {
            toExchangeRate = exchangeRateUSD;
        }
        if (to.Equals("AUD"))
        {
            toExchangeRate = exchangeRateAUD;
        }
        if (to.Equals("CAD"))
        {
            toExchangeRate = exchangeRateCAD;
        }
        if (to.Equals("EUR"))
        {
            toExchangeRate = exchangeRateEUR;
        }
        if (to.Equals("GBP"))
        {
            toExchangeRate = exchangeRateGBP;
        }
        if (to.Equals("NZD"))
        {
            toExchangeRate = exchangeRateNZD;
        }

        double amount;
        Double.TryParse(input, out amount);

        amount = (amount / fromExchangeRate) * toExchangeRate;
        amount = Math.Round(amount, 2);

        string result = Convert.ToString(amount);
        return result;
    }
```

I am not familiar with switches but is there a way that they can be used in this situation?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT

Thank you all for your input.

The following code is what I ended up using:

```
        static string RevisedConversionFunction(string input, string from, string to)
    {

        //Exchange Rates
        Dictionary<string, double> rates = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        rates.Add("USD", 1);
        rates.Add("AUD", 1.31);
        rates.Add("CAD", 1.28);
        rates.Add("EUR", 0.95);
        rates.Add("GBP", 0.68);
        rates.Add("NZD", 1.36);

        //Conversion
        double amount;
        Double.TryParse(input, out amount);
        return Convert.ToString(Math.Round(((amount / rates[from]) * rates[to]), 2));
    }
```

Comment: I am not a c# user but I think it is better to use array and loop statement


var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "USD", "exchangeRateUSD" },
    { "AUD", "exchangeRateAUD" },
    { "CAD", "exchangeRateCAD" }
};

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- I would use a Dictionary in this case
- use `decimal` instead of `double` to prevent rounding issues

Code:

```
static string RevisedConversionFunction(string input, string from, string to)
{
    Dictionary<string, decimal> dExchange = new Dictionary<string, decimal>()
    { 
        {"USD" , 1},
        {"AUD" , 1.31m},
        {"CAD" , 1.28m},
        {"EUR" , 0.95m},
        {"GBP" , 0.68m},
        {"NZD" , 1.36m}
    };

    if (dExchange.ContainsKey(from) && dExchange.ContainsKey(to))
    {
        return Math.Round((decimal.Parse(input) / dExchange[from]) * dExchange[to], 2).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // at least one currency not in the dictionary - exception handling?
        return null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Saved. That's great!

Comment: Why decimal, a double or even a float would do, this is not a typical financial / scientific calculations

Comment: `decimal` should always be used in case of money - otherwise you can get into rounding issues

Comment: Ok yes if the precision, needs to be accurate, otherwise it surely has a memory impact for such operations

Comment: Good answer. The only comment to make though is that `dExchange` should be declared outside of `RevisedConversionFunction`, otherwise it gets recreated every time the function is called.

Comment: @DavidArno currency exchange rates are changing multiple times a day so imo it's a bad idea to keep them in source code at all...

Answer (score 2):

I am not a c# user but I think it is better to use array

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "USD", "exchangeRateUSD" },
    { "AUD", "exchangeRateAUD" },
    { "CAD", "exchangeRateCAD" }
};
```

Comment: *I think it is better to use array and loop statement* Puts code for `Dictionary`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you were going to use if statements you should have else ifs as well.  The code you have there is going to check every single if even if the first one hits.  This will only check the first one (assuming the first one is true).

```
if (from.Equals("USD"))
    {
        fromExchangeRate = exchangeRateUSD;
    }
else if (from.Equals("AUD"))
    {
        fromExchangeRate = exchangeRateAUD;
    }
```

Switching it to a switch is probably a pretty solution:

```
switch(a) { case 0: ...; break; case 1: ...; break; }
```

*Typically any modern compiler that encounters a if..else if .. sequence that could be converted into a switch statement by a person, the compiler will as well.*

Answer (score 1):

Create a Mapping dictionary as follows:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, double> currencyMapping = 
    new Dictionary<string, double>
    {
      {"USD",1},
      {"AUD",1.31},
      {"CAD",1.28},
      {"EUR",0.95},
      {"GBP",0.68},
      {"NZD",1.36},   
    }
```

Now it can be used as follows, `TryGet` the value or assign the default value. Also note that `Dictionary` as it contains read only information its a `static readonly`, for one time run-time evaluation in the constructor, then it cannot be modified anywhere in the program, thus a pretty much constant information like a const, which is compile time

```
 double fromExchangeRate;
    if(!currencyMapping.TryGetValue(from,out fromExchangeRate))
      fromExchangeRate = <DefaultValue>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dictionary.

```
var exchanges = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
    ["USD"] = 1,
    ["AUD"] = 1.31,
    ["CAD"] = 1.28,
    ["EUR"] = 0.95,
    ["GBP"] = 0.68,
    ["NZD"] = 1.36,
};

double fromExchangeRate = 0;
double toExchangeRate = 0;

if (exchanges.ContainsKey(from))
{
    fromExchangeRate = exchanges[from];
}
else
{
    // 'from' not in dictionary
}


if (exchanges.ContainsKey(to))
{
    toExchangeRate = exchanges[to];
}
else
{
    // 'to' not in dictionary
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Array To reduce First Line of Code
Arrays are always fixed in size, and have to be defined like so:

```
double[] exchangeRate = new double[8];

// This means array is double[3] and cannot be changed without redefining it.
exchangeRate[0] = 1;
exchangeRate[1] = 1.31;
and so on..
```

And For String Data store it in Array like

```
String[] Data = new String[8];

// This means array is double[3] and cannot be changed without redefining it.
Data[0] = "USD";
Data[1] = "AUD";
and so on..
```

Then Use Foreach to traverse

```
foreach (String[] row in Data)
{
    if(from.Equals(Data[0]))
    {
       //Do something
    }
}
```

Same way you can do this as per your requirement..

Hopefully it will works for you .. Thank you :-)